# Black tile appear in pdf zoom in UIWebview

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

When loading the pdf in `UIWebview` it loads properly at first.But when zoomed in and out for sometime, the pdf is not rendered properly. ie in certain zoom level some of the tile area [Rectangular area] appears black and it persist in the same state afterwards.
Please see the image below

[image]

Any idea how to make this proper ?

Comment: Is this issue arriving only on iOS8? Please test this on iOS7 or iOS6 and let me know.

Comment: it appears in 7 and 8 dont know abt 6

Comment: Ok. I guess its not OS specific issue now.

Answer (score 1):

I face same issue like this, i tried to read local pdf using WKWebview and UIWebView. Somehow after I zoom in and zoom out in iPad the view become black like your view and I think its because memory issue and there is problem when rendering the html.
If you want to open pdf better just call UIDocumentInteractionController or PDFKit for above iOS 11

```
func showPDF(){
   let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: localUrl!)
   documentController.delegate = self
   documentController.presentPreview(animated: true)
}
```

And you need implement the delegate method

```
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
   return self                                                                         
}
```